# Create a group shared directory

Tags: linux, shared-directory

So I got the directory "shared".
A group named "Workers"
And I got 2 users "Bob" and "An". They both have "Workers" as group. How do I make it so that they both can share in Workers. But only users of the group "Workers".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure the directory is part of the Workers group. Make sure it is usable by the group.

```
chgrp Workers shared
chmod g+rwx shared
```

You may want to add the t flag (based on John Hascall's comment)

```
chmod g+rwxt shared
```

Comment: Consider also the 't' bit which means you must be the owner of a file in that directory to delete it -- this may (or may not) be appropriate to your needs.

Comment: And also "chmod o-rwx shared"?